# Does webContentLink in google drive ever change? so that can I use that link in my webpage

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I upload pictures in google drive and want to use the webContentLink to display them in my website. Does the webContentLink ever change? Because if it does there is no point in using it in my website...

Thank You...

Comment: I don't think `webContentLink` changes. See this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857460/google-drive-images-in-img-src-webcontentlink) and [Download Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) for additional insights. This [forum thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/LScOLOSTJPo;context-place=topicsearchin/drive/authorid$3AAPn2wQeN3Mj8uhUBHdR18Cb_YkIWHMWdkWo_YTSMKaiUh7GBCfJEAKyCXNfZX13eNWmF5GD5xQdc%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false) might also help.