# Google Drive Embedded Images sometimes don't show. HTML PAGE

Tags: html

I have looked around a bit, at solutions to embed Google Drive images and haven't found an actual solution to my issue specifically. My page loads images fine on the first load, but after a few refreshes or navigations, images no longer show, but then show again after maybe 30 minutes or so. Has anyone encountered this, or is there an explanation for this? Your assistance is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857460/google-drive-images-in-img-src-webcontentlink/42865830

Comment: @quantumPuter this post does not answer the question. I am also having this issue and also looking for a solution before migrating to amazon...

Comment: @Digao I've just noticed that this only occurs with multiple image, it doesn't happen when it is just one image.

Comment: @ThebehaliConsulting I gave up using google drive to store images. Actually, as other posts say, it is not meant for that purpose, that's why they have quotas.. you should consider moving your structure to another infrastructure. In my case, since I had space to spare, I am serving images by myself in my server using nginx. It is working just fine... and much easier to implement and maintain...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post, you need to follow specific steps to do it properly, with this information its hard to say whats the problem. Maybe create a snippet.

[link to post!(displaying-files-e-g-images-stored-in-google-drive-on-a-website)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311092/displaying-files-e-g-images-stored-in-google-drive-on-a-website)

Comment: this post is 8 years old and many things have chance since then at the API...

Comment: Thanks @Marijn, like I said, they load fine initially, so the links are okay. They just stop loading at one point, but then again reload fine some time later. The closest analogy I can think of, is a carburetor overflow... LoL..